# RabbitMQ implementation details

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue

I recently watched a nice presentation about how RabbitMQ works and it kinda intrigued on how whole AMQP implentation works.

I was considering using it for a project but I would like some answers about the following questions:

1) Is it possible to have a broker and a producer of a message at the same place? I do understand that RabbitMQ allows the use of Virtual Hosts so something like this could be possible right?

2) Can RabbitMQ transmit it's messages over two diferrent subnets? I know it can trasmit over lan or wan, but how easy it to do this over two subnets? (One answer here would actually be to have them bridged).

3) Regarding question 1, how hard would it be to fail over the broker functionality to another place in case the original broker goes down?

4) I do understand that RabbitMQ actually provides different types of message transmissions. One of those is the fanout type which is more or less similar to a broadcast action. Would it be possible though to have something that is the inversed type of that. Meaning that you have multiple producers with multiple queues that all transmit to a single consumer?

Answer (score 2):

1) It doesn't matter where the consumers/producers are, as long as they can reach (access IP:port) the broker. Virtual hosts have nothing to do with that.

2) More or less same as answer to first one, RabbitMQ us using the network and has no knowledge about what kind of networks is it in; also doesn't need to know or care.

3)Failover  is easy, look for rabbitmq [cluster](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) and [high availability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html). For the clients you'd have to take care on your own (so how to reconnect etc).

4) yes, broadcast is possible, you should have a [look at tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) and what kind of exchanges are there. **EDIT**  As zapl pointed out in the comments, you can also do the inverse of broadcast.

Comment: 4) the *inverse* of broadcasts is possible. A simple single queue with a single consumer.

Comment: Yes, but I have  read "reserved" as it actually says now, didn't even think of the typo :)